# Symmetric Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras

What is symmetric variety ?
Let G be a semisimple simply connected algebraic group over the complex numbers. Let $\sigma$ : G $\to$ G be an automorphism of order 2 and H be the sub group of G of the element fixed by by $\sigma$. Then prove that G/H is a symmetric variety.

Comment: This seems to be an exercise. From where? According to a standard definition, there is nothing to be done to solve your problem. Presumably, then, your definition is different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a [symmetric variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_variety) is a quotient $G/H$ of a reductive algebraic group $G$ by the subgroup $H$ fixed by some involution of $G$. So there is nothing to show. Symmetric varieties are a subclass of [spherical varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_variety). To give an example, consider the quotient $GL_n/O_n$, which is a symmetric variey and thus spherical. Indeed, let $GL_n$ act by conjuguation on the non-degenerate quadratic form $q(x_1, \cdots , x_n) = \sum_i x_i^2$. The orbit is isomorphic to the quotient $GL_n/O_n$. The involution $σ$ is defined by $\sigma(g) = (g^{-1})^t$.

Comment: Are number of involution single or finite or infinite ?

Comment: A single involution, but arbitrary.